# Facebook Instant Articles gives "Unclaimed URL" error

Tags: facebook, rss, feeds

I don't know which URL paste in the RSS feed.  When I try, I get the following error:

> #### Production RSS Feed
>
> Connect your RSS feed for Insntant Articles here.   Learn more about automated publishing options, including API.
>
> > #### Unclaimed URL
> >
> > The URL `https://example.com/feed/` has not been claimed for Instant Articles.   Please check to make sure you have a URL registered for your page.  For more information refer to URLs in the Publishing Articles section of the Instant Articles documentation.
>
> RSS Feed URL

[image]